# Ant deployment: Error: Unknown user permission: DataExport

Tags: ant

I m trying to deploy the profiles from production to my devleoper org.

My Package.xml is this :-

```
<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Profile</name>
</types>
```

I have retrieved the profiles but when i try to deploy i receive the following error.

```
All Component Failures:
1.  profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: DataExport
2.  profiles/EventList Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
3.  profiles/Guest License User.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
4.  profiles/LoginPage Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
5.  profiles/MarketingProfile.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: OverrideForecasts
6.  profiles/NewEventList Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
7.  profiles/ReadOnly.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ViewCaseInteraction
8.  profiles/Redirecting Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
9.  profiles/Referesh Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
10.  profiles/SolutionManager.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: OverrideForecasts
11.  profiles/Standard.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: OverrideForecasts
12.  profiles/Sys Admin %2B.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ApiUserOnly
13.  profiles/Test 1 Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
14.  profiles/Test2 Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
15.  profiles/logout Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
16.  profiles/register Profile.profile -- Error: In field: userLicense - no UserLicense named Guest User License found
17.  profiles/ContractManager.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: ApproveContract
```

How can i deploy these profiles.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have different versions of Salesforce on different orgs or different features enabled.

You can just manually remove permission which doesn't exist on the target organization from each file where it is present

Comment: But didn't the original question say they're deploying their production code to their sandbox?  In that case (assuming the sandbox is 'fresh'), I'd assume there shouldn't be this difference.

Comment: No, i am deploying the code from Production to the developer org.

Comment: As far as I know, this appears to be a bug related to old orgs having a permission that is no longer in new orgs.  You either have to remove the offending lines from the permission set xml or contact support to have that feature disabled from your production org.